# Why does perf fail to collect any samples?

Tags: linux, perf

`sudo perf top` shows "Events: 0  cycles".

`sudo perf record -ag sleep 10` shows

```
[ perf record: Woken up 1 time to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.154 MB perf.data (~6725 samples) ]
```

However, `sudo perf report` shows "The perf.data file has no samples!". Also I checked the `perf.data` recorded and confirmed there is no any samples in it.

The system is "3.2.0-86-virtual #123-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:25:12 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux".
perf version 3.2.69

Inputs are appreciated.

Comment: what is the file size of perf.data ? How you checked out dumping the trace as text using perf report ?

Comment: The file size looks normal:-rw------- 1 root root 146144 Sep 13 22:28 perf.data

Answer (score 3):

There may be no real samples on idle virtualized system (your linux kernel version has "-virtual" suffix); or there may be no access to hardware counters (`-e cycles`), which are used by default.

Try to profile some real application like

```
 echo '2^2345678%2'| sudo perf record /usr/bin/bc
```

Also check software counters like `-e cpu-clock`:

```
 echo '2^2345678%2'| sudo perf record -e cpu-clock /usr/bin/bc
```

You may try `perf stat` (`perf stat -d`) with same example to find which basic counters are really incremented in your system:

```
 echo '2^2345678%2'| sudo perf stat /usr/bin/bc
```

About "(~6725 samples)" output - perf record doesn't not count samples in its output, it just **estimates** their count but this estimation is *always wrong*. There is some fixed part of any perf.data file without any sample, it may use tens of kb in system-wide mode; and estimation incorrectly counts this part as containing some events of mean length.

Comment: what is the echo for?